# Gmail message sent Pop Up

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How to generate this popup at the bottom of the screen, which contains some text about the action taken and sometimes a button to view the changes we saved? Like in Gmail Android Application, when we send a mail it shows 'Message sent' at the bottom of the screen and a button which says 'View'. I have also seen this in other applications like Google Clock and Facebook.

Comment: Hey, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Use android component [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar).

Comment: I thought it was a custom toast but it didn't worked.

Comment: Thank You It's clear to me now. Snackbar is the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Snackbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/Snackbar) class.

```
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(yourLayout, "Snackbar", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```